# How can I speed up animation render time?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation

I'm trying to do a test render of a 20 second animation, but it's taking 3 hours to render at 144p with 8 samples in Cycles. I noticed that during the very short moment that the frame is actually being rendered, it says that 20 seconds has already passed for the rendering of the frame, even though the actual rendering hasn't started. I assume this is Blender preparing the scene for rendering. Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110952/render-speed-up-cycles

Comment: That seems to be related to the actual rendering part and noise, instead of the pre-render section of rendering a frame. I didn't see any results in performance from the steps.