# Performing a quick / rough render

Tags: rendering, performance

Is there a way to reduce the quality of a render in order to output it quicker? I'm currently using the Cycles Render in Blender 2.79 and find it quite slow on my old machine.

It would be good if I could render something quickly in a lower quality just to get a rough idea of how things will look, before I commit the time to rendering it properly.

The same goes for the real-time 'Rendered' view.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a new version of Blender, in some ways it is more optimized and organised.

Anyway, these steps are similar in all versions

1. Change amount of samples to around 10-20.
2. Reduce resolution (size of the output)
3. Multiply viewport pixel size

This will make your render look really grainy and crappy. Just like you asked.

[image]

Comment: See also   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110952/render-speed-up-cycles  _"Why don't you use a new version of Blender? It's more optimized and organised isn't it? "_   Most pertinent (IMO, given OP's ref to old machine) here is the hardware.  New software is designed to run on new hardware. This is where blender walks the free open source tightrope.  A lot of machines, that happily ran blender,  required update  or were "left behind"  in 2.8x

Comment: thank you, works nicely! also my machine is unfortunately too old to run the current Blender release as per @batFINGER's comment... v2.79 works nicely however