# increase rendering speed in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

This question has been asked before but answers didn't work that well for me.

I am making a animation at 720p on Cycles

i3-7 gen , NVidia Geforce 940mx, I have enabled both of them in CUDA.

I am focused on something between quality and time

My scene has

- Volumetrics,
- disabled refractive caustics
- tile size is 256 X 256
- light bounces set to around 4-5
- volumetrics to 7 samples
- sampling to 100
- enabled blender's optix denoiser
- and a simple composition node tree

Still it renders a single image in 15-20 minutes and my animation is around 430 frames.

Any further ways to reduce render time?

The image is of the scene render from EEVEE to give a idea what it looks like, the purple flame was removed

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render Speed up (cycles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110952/render-speed-up-cycles)

Comment: Hello :). What other answers have you tried already? You can add links into your post.

Comment: Hi. It is good that you did some research on existing answers, but when doing so please link to the questions you went through, and state why they didn't hlep, so we don't end up suggesting the same things.